# node.js v0.11.14 as service with --harmony

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, forever

I am using Amazon linux on EC2 and node.js v0.11.14.

I need to start node as service with parameter harmony

```
node --harmony app.js
```

how to achieve this with forever or other package?

I found answers like `forever start -c "node --harmony" app.js` but this is not working.

Comment: I know that is not your question but I think you should use pm2. Is the next generation of node.js in production enviroments. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: how to use `--harmony` with pm2 ?

Comment: pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony"

Comment: @HaroldFinch I decided to go 'pm2' after your comment. Please provide answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For production environment, personally, you should give a try to pm2. PM2 is an awesome process manager for nodejs. There are features like: Load balancer, running the app forever even when the server restarts and a lot more that you can read here: 
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

To pass v8 arguments using pm2 you can use --node-args:

```
pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony"
```

To pass arguments to the v8 engine and app.js you have to use double dashes.

```
pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony" -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now, your node is running with `--harmony` and you can access the args via `process.argv` array.

Comment: Thanks @Harold maybe you can also answer my second question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825220/restart-node-js-after-crash-in-pm2